# Why didn't they just shoot Rose the Hat?

Tags: plot-explanation, doctor-sleep

I have never read the *Doctor Sleep* book and only saw the movie last night, but from my understanding, the Knots (quasi-vampires) are prone to bodily harms just like normal humans. This is further shown in the movie when Dan shot and killed most of the group with a deer rifle.

My questions are:

- Why did they have to lure Rose the Hat back to the Overlook hotel? Couldn't they just create a trap, home-alone style, with explosives or other deadly things? So that when Rose follows them in, she would be immediately blown up or killed in other ways.
- In the movie, Dan was only fending off Rose with an axe, why not a long-distance weapon like a gun? It seemed like Rose just walked in the hotel lobby and would have been easily shot if Dan had a gun.
- Why go through the trouble of unleashing the demons from the hotel? They would be unlocked from the boxes and kill Dan too. If he just wanted to destroy the hotel, why not just set it on fire from the outside?

Comment: Because movies. Apart from that let's not dismiss Rose's psychic abilities. It's possible the Overlook itself was a noisy enough battle ground where she wouldn't be able to anticipate or locate them as easily as if they were just plotting a roadside ambush with the guns Danny inexplicably no longer has. Maybe the hotel was needed to consume her as only the Overlook has it within itself to do so... mere speculation though. I sort of wondered the same thing.